# Google App Engine firewall allow requests only from another Google App Engine App

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I've followed some other solved questions on SO and [Google's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/creating-firewalls?hl=es-419#allowing_requests_from_your_services) about this but none of it is working.

My scenario: I have 2 Google Cloud projects. One for my front-end and another for the back-end. I only want to allow requests to my back-end project from my front-end project. So in App Engine from the back-end project I've set the following rules:

```
Priority    Action     IPs  
1           Allow      0.1.0.40     
2           Allow      10.1.0.41        
default     Deny        *
```

Both projects use Standard env.

What's wrong with these settings?

Thanks!

**EDIT 1**

I've found out that if I allow my IP in the back-end project it works. Why is this? Isn't it supposed to be sending the requests from a Google Cloud IP or something similar?

Comment: are you running the frontend application locally ? also, app engine doesn't just have 1 public ip, it's a range of ip shared among all app engine services, what you are doing is not isolating your backend at all. If you want to restrict (and audit) rest calls, I suggest you to use cloud endpoints :)

Comment: No, both Apps are running on GCloud. The IP I'm allowing is what Google suggests in their documentation

Comment: gcloud is a cli utility built by google, if you are running it doing gcloud app run or similar on your local machine, that's why :) Also, as I've said, app engine standard is a PaaS you don't have 1 single ip to whitelist

Comment: Both Apps, front and back are running on Google, not locally @Pievis

Comment: ok, still please read here about app engine static ip pool and why you shouldn't use them: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/#static-ip - in general what you are doing is a bad idea

Answer (score 0):

You should consider securing your back-end using [Identity-Aware Proxy (IAP)](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/app-engine-quickstart).

> IAP lets you establish a central authorization layer for applications
>   accessed by HTTPS, so you can use an application-level access control
>   model instead of relying on network-level firewalls

Here you can find the official documentation:

[Identity-Aware Proxy documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/).